# How to compare the outcomes of a 3-variable test in a grid?

Tags: data-visualization, variable

If I do a test; say, measuring the brightness of a room; and I have two variables (e.g. lamp on/off and window open/closed), I can display the results in a spreadsheet like so:

|  | Lamp: On | Lamp: Off |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Window: Open** | 100% | 40% |
| **Window: Closed** | 60% | 0% |

But how do I display the results if I include a third variable (e.g. torch on/off)?

I realise a spreadsheet probably won't cut it anymore, so I tried looking at other types of grids (e.g. isometric) but I couldn't find one that would allow each of the possible options to all converge at a point where I could write the answer for that set of options. And I've seen those logic puzzles where you have a 'stepped-grid', but that requires at least one of the variables' options to be duplicated, and you still don't get a single set of answers (they're spread out over the grid).

So my question is basically this: what's the simplest way to visualise data (like the example above), but with three variables instead of two?

Answer (score 1):

Comments:

By including the 'torch' you have moved from a two-dimensional table
to a three=dimensional table, so for a table in a report you need to
think how to handle the third dimension on a flat page. One Possibility is shown below.
(The exact configuration may depend on whether totals need to be shown and whether effects are strictly additive.)

```
             Both On         One On            Both Off
             -------     ---------------       --------- 
   Window                 Lamp     Torch         
      
    Open       100%        90%       60%          50%        
    Closed      50%        40%       10%           0%
```

Another possibility:

```
            Lamp Only       Torch Only      Lamp & Torch
            ----------      ----------      -------------
Window      On     Off      On     Off      Both  Neither
                 
 Open       90%    50%      60%    50%      100%     50%
 Closed     40%     0%      10%     0%       50%      0%
```